# Python HTTP server not responding on POST request

Tags: python, post, httpserver

I would like to make a HTTP server using python, to host my website. I've implemented do_GET() method and it works fine, but when I try the POST method, server is not responding until I reload the page. Then it wakes up, tring to complete the POST, but realizing that the connection has ended. After that it serves the GET method (because I reloaded the page) and continue running normally.

I'm using jQuery on client side, but i also tried html form. It's no change even if i open the page in another browser, so it must be an exception on server side.

Here is the client javascript:

```
function Send()
        {
            jQuery.post("address", "Blah!", function (data) {
                //get response
                alert(data);
            });
        }
```

And here is the server code (I'm using python 3.3.4):

```
class MyHTTPRequestHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print("Data: " + str(self.rfile.read(), "utf-8")) #show request

        response = bytes("This is the response.", "utf-8") #create response

        self.send_response(200) #create header
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(response)))
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(response) #send response
```

This is the log from server:

```
10.175.72.200 - - [01/Apr/2014 19:11:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Data: Blah!
10.175.72.200 - - [01/Apr/2014 19:11:47] "POST /address HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.175.72.200', 2237)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 306, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 332, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 345, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socketserver.py", line 666, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 400, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\server.py", line 388, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:\Users\Jirek\Desktop\Server\server.py", line 45, in do_POST
    self.wfile.write(response) #send response
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 317, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
10.175.72.200 - - [01/Apr/2014 19:11:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

You can see, on the first line is classical GET request. Then I call the POST from browser and nothing happens until the reload. At that point the server writes the rest of the log.

Answer (score 12):

Problem solved! It's in the line where the code loads received data (in `do_POST()`). I just had to specify the amount of data to read.

So, just don't use `rfile.read()`, but `rfile.read(numberOfBytes)`. How big is the POST message is saved in headers: `numberOfBytes = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])`

The repaired method:

```
def do_POST(self):
    length = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
    print("Data: " + str(self.rfile.read(length), "utf-8"))

    response = bytes("This is the response.", "utf-8") #create response

    self.send_response(200) #create header
    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(response)))
    self.end_headers()

    self.wfile.write(response) #send response
```